# Is it poor practice to build an SQL query using WHERE 1=1 AND 

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

I'm writing a PHP script that builds an SQL query by concatenating the string and adding conditions to the `WHERE` clause as needed.

Would it be better practice to use `WHERE 1=1` so that the first condition is satisfied and the script can just concatenate an `AND x = 'y'` to the query, or should I write the extra code to check if a clause has been added and if not, add the `AND` ?

The first solution allows for cleaner code in the script but just seems wrong to me.

Confusing question, I know. Let me know if I need to be more clear.

Rob

Comment: What scripting language? Most of them have "join" operations on arrays to accomplish just that.

Comment: Using PHP, forgot to mention that!

Comment: **SQL Injection** is ringing in my ears...

Comment: Lucero, how does using a `1=1` clause open the door to SQL injection? All of the inputs used for the query are being sanitized.

Comment: It's of course not the `1=1` but building a SQL query by string concatenation. Sanitizing the input is sometimes harder than it seems; for instance, there used to be severe URL traversal bugs in IIS because one could escape Unicode characters and such. Avoiding string concatenated SQL altogether is the only right thing to do IMHO.

Comment: @Rob, you are new to SO, so let me explain.  Anytime anyone mentions dynamic sql, injection attacks are mentioned.

Comment: @Lucero, you can easily build a prepared statement using string concatenation.

Comment: @jeroen, I only wanted to point out the dangers of strings concatenation, as many aren't really aware of them. Often if you do use prepared statements you don't build it from scratch using string concatenation but rather do checks à la `((x IS NULL) OR (x = tbl.x))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create an array of the conditions as you determine which ones you need. when you're ready to build the query, check if the array is empty... if it is not empty then print "WHERE" followed by the elements joined together with "AND"s.

### edit

since you're using PHP, I'll give some example code:

```
<?php
    $conditions = array();
    if($foo == "bar") {
        $conditions[] = "some_table.foo = 'bar'";
    }
    if($show_future) {
        $conditions[] = "some_table.entry_date > NOW()";
    }
    $sql_where = count($conditions) ? "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $conditions) : "";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table $sql_where;";
?>
```

Comment: Just for the sake of being picky: `empty($conditions)` ;-)

Comment: but then Ty W would need to switch the expressions around.

Comment: does an empty array evaluate to true or false? for example could you do: $conditions ? "this" : "that";

Comment: Thanks! It works great. Only thing was you have `$implode()` when it should be `implode()`

Comment: To avoid operator precedence trouble, I would strongly recommend using `"WHERE (" . implode(") AND (", $conditions) .")"` instead, so that each condition will be wrapped in parentheses.

Answer (score 10):

No, the SQL optimizer will just throw the `1=1` away and be on its way.

Comment: Agreed, just make where clauses that are brain-dead easy to optimize (so that your DB engine will catch it) and move on.  In a perfect world, you would not implement that BS, but a man's gotta deliver software, you know?

Comment: That's what you'd think, but SQL Server (which has the most powerful optimizer) doesn't!  See this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/270ad8ad-e3f4-468c-84fc-d8dfa433ffa6

Comment: @Andomar, that link covers `id != id` not 1=1, my quick test on my system using `set showplan_all on` shows that the `1=1` is removed.

Comment: @KM: Looks like you're right, same on my machine.  I expected `id = id` to be just as predictably true as `1=1`

Answer (score 2):

To expand of Ty W's answer, since you're using PHP:

```
$clauses = array();

// Optionally add one or more clauses to the array like this:
$clauses[] = "test = 2";

// Now generate the WHERE clause:
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Table ';
$sql .= count($clauses) ? ('WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $clauses)) : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be too offended to see a `1=1` in SQL queries, if it was explained somewhere.

That said, if I were doing it in Python, I'd probably do something like:

```
query = (where_clauses or ["1=1"]).join(" AND ")
```

So that "real" queries wouldn't need the strange `1=1`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I wouldn't worry about performance at all, until you actually hit a performance issue.

That said, something like `1=1` can have surprising performance consequences.  For an example which caught me by suprise, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872195/unexpected-table-scan-for-id-id).  But then again, there are also cases where prefixing `1=1` will make your query faster!  The wise programmer optimizes based on measurement.  It's just impossible to predict how a change will impact performance.

Answer (score 1):

While the 1=1 thing ain't pretty, code generators often do things that ain't pretty. If this is not code that needs to be maintained or understood by anyone (other than the developer building and debugging the generator), then I don't believe the ugliness matters.

Answer (score 1):

PHP offers a nice little function for this: `implode`. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

You can use it as follows:

```
$rawConditions = array("x='y'", "z='a'");
$conditions = "WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $rawConditions);
// $conditions == "WHERE x='y' AND z='a'"
```